# Почему в данном случае не ставится запятая перед "как"?

Tags: пунктуация

Предложение:
"Вода в море как желтоватая листва акаций."

Мне почему-то очень хочется поставить перед *как* запятую, но по факту она тут не ставится. Кто может объяснить, почему?

Comment: Если хочется, отчего же не ставить?

Comment: Вам делать нечего что ли? Меня интересует правильность с точки зрениия русского языка, чтобы в других подобных случаях не ошибаться. Неужели не понятно?

Comment: Это — речь мужа. Значит, понятие «сравнение» вам знакомо (с точки зрения русского языка).

Comment: Я знаю, что сравнения выделяются запятыми. Но думаю, что учебнику по подготовке абитуриентов можно доверять, а запятая там не ставится в данном случае.

Comment: Если это тот самый факт, то он не означает, что никаких других знаков ставить не надо, ведь это «предложение» нельзя назвать предложением.

Comment: вообще не понял о чем вы. По делу так и не ответили.

Comment: Как же ответить по такой детали, как запятая, если не ясно: это предложение или нет. Если это предложение, то какого типа?

Comment: Отождествит оборот автор и объявит сказуемым, а не сравнением, — дело его. К тому же контекст фразы не ясен, да и задание-то не на запятую нацелено, а на тире.

Answer (score 6):

> Почему в данном случае не ставится запятая перед как?
>
> *Вода в море **как** желтоватая **листва** акаций.*

***как листва*** в этом предложении -- сказуемое.

---

[См.](http://orthographia.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=125#pp125):

> **§ 90.** Обороты со сравнительными союзами (частицами) ***как, словно, будто, точно, как будто, что*** не выделяются запятыми в
>   следующих случаях:
>
> <...>
>
> в) если оборот является сказуемым: Снег у крыльца ***как песок зыбучий.***